# If my friend has passport and b2 visa, does she need an invitation lettter to show at airport upon arrival in the usa in order to stay in my home?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airports, b1-b2-visas

My friend is flying to usa this coming week. She wants to stay for 2 months and already has return ticket. But the money she had doesn't show to be enough for duration of stay. Is she allowed to say she is staying with friends or does she have to have letter of invitation to prove it?
Or do the officers at airport even care?

Comment: Are the friends expected to pay for things like food?

Answer (score 2):

> Or do the officers at airport even care?

**ESPECIALLY** with CBP, **never** assume they don't care

> Is she allowed to say she is staying with friends

Yes

> or does she have to have letter of invitation to prove it?

This would be a nice to have in case of secondary inspection, but, if they have any doubt and put them in secondary, you can expect that they would call the host (just make sure they have their phone number)

> She wants to stay for 2 months and already has return ticket.

This is the major roadblock. People are expected to have ties to their country, leaving 2 months and without enough money, might end them in trouble

If the B2 has been applied for that specific 2 month trip, then they're likely not in trouble, if it's a reuse of an existing B2, then there might be more scrutiny

Comment: My mother usually visits us on a B2 visa for periods of months, and usually there is no issue unless she's coming too frequently (happened in 2022, but only some heat from the CBP officer, no secondary inspection at all). She is a retired homeowner in her home country (so there are ties) and always has a return trip already ticketed when she enters.

Comment: I agree with @LuísGuilherme.  A 2-month stay might invite some closer scrutiny, but it might not, and it certainly will not be, by itself, a "major roadblock."  Lots of people visit the US for as long or longer to stay with friends or family.